# How to check the smoothness of the following function?

Tags: complex-analysis, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

I was solving a problem which boiled down to checking the smoothness of the following function.

$$
\tilde{p} (z) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{p(1/z)} &\quad z\neq 0 \\ 
                               0 &\quad z = 0.\end{cases}
$$

where $p$ is a polynomial not identically zero and the domain of the function is chosen so that $p(1/z) \neq 0$ in all of the domain.

Continuity of the function is easy to see as $z \to 0$ implies $p(1/z) \to \infty$ hence $\tilde{p}(z) \to 0$. But I do not see how to imply smoothness of $\tilde{p}(z)$. Here I do not want it to be holomorphic, it is enough if I can see that $\tilde{p}$ is smooth as function of two variables.

Comment: Do you also want to show analyticity?

Comment: @edm. No, I just need to show that $\tilde{p}$ is smooth as a map from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to itself. But looking at the expression it seems that it could be holomorphic as well, but I don't see how I can prove or disprove such questions.

Answer (score 1):

The reciprocal map $\rho: \ z\mapsto{1\over z}$ is continuous througout its domain of definition $\dot{\mathbb C}:={\mathbb C}\setminus\{0\}$. Let $\Omega$ be the envisaged domain of $\tilde p$. Since it is assumed that $p(1/z)\ne0$ for all points $z\in\dot \Omega$ the composition
$$\tilde p(z)=(\rho\circ p\circ\rho)(z)\qquad(z\in\dot\Omega)$$
is continuous throughout $\dot\Omega$.

The point $z=0$ needs special treatment. If ${\rm deg}(p)\geq1$ then $$\lim_{z\to0}p(1/ z)=\lim_{w\to\infty}p(w)=\infty\ ,$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{z\to0}\tilde p(z)=\lim_{z\to0}{1\over p(1/z)}=0=\tilde p(0)\ .$$
It follows that $\tilde p$ is continuous  at $z=0$ in this case.  If, however, ${\rm deg}(p)=0$ then $p(z)\equiv c\ne0$, and we have $$\lim_{z\to0}p(1/ z)=\lim_{w\to\infty}p(w)=c\ ,$$ and therefore
$$\lim_{z\to0}\tilde p(z)=\lim_{z\to0}{1\over p(1/z)}={1\over c}\ne\tilde p(0)\ ,$$
so that $\tilde p$ is not continuous at $0$ in this case.

Comment: This means that if $p$ is a constant polynomial, then we have a trouble. Thanks for pointing this out, and I think the following will resolve this problem. We can redefine $\tilde{p}(z)$ by defining it to be $1/c$ everywhere. Then $\tilde{p}$ will be smooth. Also, I realized later that in the other case we can use the fact that on $\dot{\Omega}$, $\tilde{p}$ will be holomorphic and $0$ will be removable singularity making $\tilde{p}$ holomorphic on all of $\Omega$ hence smooth.